# Protect Magento Directories

Tags: magento-1.8, htaccess

I am just about to put a Magento site live and wondered what the best method is to protecting Magento's directories.

At the moment I have simply stuck in the following into my htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(var) - [F,L]
```

This only protects the /var folder should I protect any others and is this the best way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default magento protects the folders that need protecting.
For example in the `var` folder has its own `.htaccess` file with this content.

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

So does the `media/customer` folder.
and there may be others.
So unless you deleted something there is no need to take special precautions for protecting folders.

Comment: Thanks it would seem as though someone deleted it

Comment: I have website in subdoamin , in var folder there is .htaccess with the code as you mentioned it but still in backend it says Your web server is configured incorrectly. As a result, configuration files with sensitive information are accessible from the outside. Please contact your hosting provider.

is there any extra step for subdoamins